# Pasting Image to <div> is pasting a small image multiple times to fit the Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am using the code from the below CodePen link to paste an image to Div but it is pasting the image multiple times if I paste a small image. If you click on the div after pasting it then it shows the image multiple times in the div. 
I want it to show the image only once rather than filling up the div with the multiple images which are the same

http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/IoJbg

```
 $('.active').removeClass('active');
 $this.addClass('active');

 $this.toggleClass('contain');

 $width.val($this.data('width'));
 $height.val($this.data('height'));
 if ($this.hasClass('contain')) {
 $this.css({'width':$this.data('width'), 'height':$this.data('height'), 'z-   index':'10'})
 } else {
 $this.css({'width':'', 'height':'', 'z-index':''})
 }

})
})
```

[multiple images in div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tXEc.png)

Comment: try 'background-repeat: no-repeat;' for image css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are toggling CSS class `.contain`, and so toggling its [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). This includes the following CSS:

```
.contain {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

When you click, this class is removed, and `background-size` reverts to its default of showing the image at original size.

Additionally, because the default [`background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) value is `repeat`, which repeats the image in both directions to cover the element.

The simple fix to stop the repeating is to add

```
.target {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

but note this will not resize the element to the size of a single image.

Answer (score 1):

Try background-repeat property.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

```js
$('.active').removeClass('active');
 $this.addClass('active');

 $this.toggleClass('contain');

 $width.val($this.data('width'));
 $height.val($this.data('height'));
 if ($this.hasClass('contain')) {
 $this.css({'width':$this.data('width'), 'height':$this.data('height'), 'z-   index':'10', 'background-repeat':'no-repeat'})
 } else {
 $this.css({'width':'', 'height':'', 'z-index':'','background-repeat':'no-repeat'})
 }

})
})
```

Comment: That Worked. Thank you.